# run 7zip commands in sas data set eg call system()

Tags: unix, path, sas, 7zip

I want to use 7zip command line from sas. I confirmed these commands work from the command line, but I can't get it to work in a sas program. I think this has to do with setting the unix path in SAS. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

```
data _null_;
  length command1 command2 $1000;
  command1 = 'set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-zip\';
  command2 = '7z x "\\mypath\zip.zip" -pmypassword -y -o"\\mypath"';
  call system(command1);
  call system(command2);
run;
```

Comment: Is SAS running on Unix or Windows? Do the commands work on the machine that SAS is running on?

Answer (score 1):

I use it all the time.  Here is an example that zips a file from my work folder and adds a password to the zip.  Windows example obviously.  If running in a corporate environment you may want to ensure you have access to execute shell commands from within SAS (such as `%sysexec`).

```
%sysexec "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -y -pMyPassword %sysfunc(pathname(work))\DestinationFilename.zip  %sysfunc(pathname(work))\SourceFilename.csv;
```